# Error in blastpgp: empty output file and checkpoint file not generated

Tags: blast

I am trying to run psitBLASTn with the following command:

```
blastall -p psitblastn -d GCA_900660155.1_ASM90066015v1_genomic_Hofstenia_miamia.fna -i S_cerevisiae_all_prot_uniq_join.fa -o test_psitblastn.out -m '8 qseqid qgi qlen sseqid bitscore length pident qcovs evalue' -a 20
```

Although blastall documentation says the checkpoint file is optional, I get the next error:

[blastall] FATAL ERROR: PSI-TBLASTN requires that a checkpoint file be specified (use the -R option).

I tried to generate the checkpoint file using blastpgp (with the same arguments) and it is not working, the output file (test_blastpgp.out) is empty and the checkpoint file (test.chk) is not generated:

```
blastpgp -d GCA_900660155.1_ASM90066015v1_genomic_Hofstenia_miamia.fna -i S_cerevisiae_all_prot_uniq_join.fa -m '8 qseqid qgi qlen sseqid bitscore length pident qcovs evalue' -o test_blastpgp.out -Q ./test.chk
```

I already ran tblastn with the same database and same query and I do get some results.

Do you have any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Do you know if there is a way to generate the checkpoint file with tblastn?

Comment: Update:


I used the next command to generate the checkpoint file (using swissprot database):


blastpgp -i S_cerevisiae_all_prot_uniq_join.fa -d swissprot -j 2 -C ./S_cerevisiae_prot_j2.chk -a 10


Then I ran:


blastall -p psitblastn -d GCA_900660155.1_ASM90066015v1_genomic_Hofstenia_miamia.fna -i S_cerevisiae_all_prot_uniq_join.fa -o test_psitblastn.out -m '8 qseqid qgi qlen sseqid bitscore length pident qcovs evalue’ -a 20 -R S_cerevisiae_prot_j2.chk


and I get the error:


[blastall] FATAL ERROR:  Blast_PosReadCheckpoint: Failed to recover data

Answer (score 0):

It seems blastall and blastpgp are not the best way to perform psi-tBLASTn. I solved it with the following commands:

## to generate the checkpoint file:

```
psiblast -db swissprot -out_pssm S_cerevisiae_psitblastn.chk -query S_cerevisiae_all_prot_uniq_join.fa -num_iterations 5 -num_alignments 0 -out S_cerevisiae_psitblastn.out -num_threads 10
```

PSSM matrix against my database:

```
tblastn  -in_pssm S_cerevisiae_psitblastn.chk -db GCA_900660155.1_ASM90066015v1_genomic_Hofstenia_miamia.fna -out S_cerevisiae_Hofstenia_miamia_psitblastn.out -num_threads 10 -outfmt '6 qseqid qgi qlen sseqid bitscore length pident qcovs evalue qstart qend sstart send qseq sseq'
```